# A segfault occurred when calling pkt->print()

Tags: gem5

When I use `pkt->print()` in the `bool CommMonitor::recvTimingReq(PacketPtr pkt)` function in `gem5/src/mem/comm_monitor.cc` file, a segmentation error occurred. This surprised me.

I just changed

```
`DPRINTF(CommMonitor, "Received %s response \n", pkt->isRead()? "Read": pkt->isWrite()? "Write": "non read/write");`
```

to

```
`DPRINTF( CommMonitor, "Received %s response %s \n", pkt->isRead()? "Read": pkt->isWrite()? "Write": "non read/write", pkt->print());`
```

It just calls pkt->print() at the end.
I am operating on the latest version of gem5, how can this be?